# Rails update model wont work : No route matches, missing required keys: [:id]

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms, ruby-on-rails-4

I just started working on my second Rails project and am having some trouble with something that seems pretty basic. I am completely confounded though.

I've set up two models, User and Profile. A Profile belongs_to a User and the User has_one Profile.
I am setting up the edit form for a Profile right now and cannot get past this. The edit form loads correctly and inserts the data in the database but when I submit the form I get the following error

```
No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"profiles", :format=>nil, :id=>#<Profile id: 7, user_id: 7, content: "Fill this in", created_at: "2015-01-08 19:08:22", updated_at: "2015-01-08 19:08:22", title: "fooobar", department: "one bar", school: "dsadsa", education: "two bar", academic_focus: "my bar is broken", website: "who bar is bokrbne">} missing required keys: [:id]
```

My models look like this

```
Class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :profile, :class_name => 'Profile', :foreign_key => 'user_id'
  attr_accessor :remember_token
end

class Profile < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user, :class_name => "User", :foreign_key => 'user_id'
  attr_accessor :id
    validates :content, presence: true, length: {maximum: 5000}
    validates :user_id, presence: true
end
```

This is the form. I've tried various ways of adding a url: parameter to form_for but had no luck.

```
    <%= form_for @profile do |f| %> 

            <%= f.label :title, class: 'col-lg-3 control-label' %>
                    <%= f.text_field :title, class: 'form-control' %>

            <%= f.label :department, class: 'col-lg-3 control-label' %>
                    <%= f.text_field :department, class: 'form-control' %>

            <%= f.label :school, class: 'col-lg-3 control-label' %>
                    <%= f.text_field :school, class: 'form-control' %>

            <%= f.label :education, class: 'col-lg-3 control-label' %>
                    <%= f.text_field :education, class: 'form-control' %>

            <%= f.label :academic_focus, class: 'col-lg-3 control-label' %>
                    <%= f.text_field :academic_focus, class: 'form-control' %>

            <%= f.label :website, class: 'col-lg-3 control-label' %>
                    <div class="col-lg-8">
                    <%= f.text_field :website, class: 'form-control' %>
        <%= f.hidden_field :id %>

    <%= f.submit "Save changes", class: "btn btn-primary" %>
    <% end %><!-- End of Form -->
```

Finally, here is the controller I am using.

```
class ProfilesController < ApplicationController
    include ApplicationHelper
    def index
        # @profiles = Profile.limit(5)
        @profiles = Profile.limit(15)
    end

    def show
        @profile = Profile.find(params[:id])
    end

    def new

    end

    def create
        @profile = Profile.new(profile_params)
        if @profile.save
            #successful save
                    flash[:success] = "Look at that. Ur Profile was ssaved"
            redirect_to @profile
        else
            #unsuccesful
            render 'new'
        end
    end

    def edit
        @user = current_user
        @profile = Profile.find(@user.id)
    end

    def update
        @profile = Profile.find(params[:id])

        if @profile.update_attributes!(profile_params)
            flash[:notice] = 'The User is successfully updated!'
            redirect_to edit_profile_path
        else
            flash[:error] = @profile.errors.full_messages[0]
            redirect_to edit_user_path
        end
    end

    def view
        @profile = Profile.find(params[:id])
    end

    private 
        def profile_params
            params.require(:profile).permit(:id, :user_id, :content, :title, :department, :school, :education, :academic_focus, :website)
        end

end
```

It is weird because I am using pretty much the exact same code I use for editing/creating users, but it isn't working. I figure it has something to do with relationship in the database.

Any insight would be much appreciated.

Thanks.

EDIT #1
Here's a photo of what happens when I submit the form
[image: After form submit]

EDIT #2 
If that image is too small here is a better one 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/vcIrK.png

EDIT #3 
I changed the form_for arguments to

```
    <%= form_for @profile, url: profile_update_path(@profile) do |f| %>
```

Now when the form is submitted I get this error

```
undefined method `profile_update_path' for #<#<Class:0x007fe1ae0e5618>:0x007fe1aca90458>
```

Comment: Could you confirm that the form would submit correctly, and update the data? It sounds that it's redirecting incorrectly (based on your statement that it inserts the data in the DB). But in order to confirm this, we need to understand whether the form hits `update` at all.

Comment: When I submit the form I get the "no routes matching....." error I posted at the top of this question

Comment: OK, so then if I understand the event sequence correctly it'll load the edit page successfully. You then submit it, and then it generates this error?

Comment: Yeah, when I submit this error comes up

Comment: Could you dump the server logs for one complete pass into a pastebin?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the attr_accessor :id statement, it's likely interfering with the ActiveRecord default accessors in some way.